# Implementation of weak function as static function

Tags: c, function, static, weak-linking

If I implement function as weak function in this way for example:

a.h:

```
int func1();
```

a.c:

```
#include "a.h"
__attribute__((weak)) int func1() {
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to implement this function in another file, for example X.c as a static function? for example:

```
#include "a.h"
static int func1(void) {   <<----------- error
  ...
}
```

I tried to do it but I got this error:

```
error: static declaration of `func1` follows non-static declaration
```

But I'm not sure why I can't to do that.. After all, this is a static function only in `X.c` file..

Comment: Yes, but it uses the same name as the function you just imported using `#include "a.h"`  I'd say, at best, this is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the .h file with some prototype of the function `func1`

Then you try to define it in the file wich includes that definition. The definition and declaration do not match. The compiler doesn't know which one to use and it is complaining about it. You need to have the same prototype and definition - otherwise, it will fail.